# DNN Errors 7.02.02

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have just download the DNN package no source and source version too opened it in visual studio 2012 in building it is showing these errors. 
I unblock the zip folder before extracting. It works fine when I configure it through netmgr.exe option IIS. I want to do that from visual studio. P.S I am using windows 8.1

```
Error   1   Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetNuke.Web.DDRMenu' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. C:\Users\Umair\Downloads\DNN_Platform_07.02.02_Install\admin\ControlPanel\RibbonBar.ascx    8   
Error   2   The file '/DNN_Platform_07.02.02_Install/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx' does not exist.  C:\Users\Umair\Downloads\DNN_Platform_07.02.02_Install\admin\ControlPanel\RibbonBar.ascx    9   
Error   3   Unknown server tag 'dnn:MENU'.  C:\Users\Umair\Downloads\DNN_Platform_07.02.02_Install\admin\ControlPanel\RibbonBar.ascx    13
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to do custom module development, you shouldn't bother opening up DNN in Visual Studio, it isn't necessary.

Comment: I want don't to use IIS for dnn as visual studio have built in virual iis system. Just I open as website in VS and then rebuild and will not have any problem or error in that thats all I want. P.S. Do you know how to reset the DNN installation like in nopcommerce site deleting the setting.txt file bring the installation wizard again.

Comment: IIS is the only way I recommend working with DNN. After 11 years on the platform, there is no better way to work with it

Comment: To be honest with a recent VS version just starting up the website should work. As long as you ignore the errors. Why would you expect perfect operation from DNN in the first place?

Comment: Now I am ignoring those errors now I want the installation wizard again on my existing platform any idea?

Comment: Thanks problems solved :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you're supposed to even try to compile the website they distribute. It should come with everything already compiled for you. Disable building for the website project from the build options dialog to get rid of spurious errors if you have other projects you'd like to compile in the same solution.

I'm not all too surprised there's a few errors in there (It's DNN, what did you expect?)

Comment: yes by passing these error will work however but I am afraid that in the long run it will not stop working. By using IIS it is also by passing the errors I am just wondering why are these errors .

Comment: The web forms validation thing in Visual Studio isn't 100% accurate and easily gets confused by some things. However it's only a validation step and the compiler that runs when the website actually uses those parts has the final say. An IDE is not what defines what's valid. That's the compiler's job.

Comment: yes you are right but here there are errors of missing components I checked that in the directories too that are present. So I manage to do that with IIS and then in Visual Studio error automatically gone.. This is not the solution but it worked for me..